# Using different intensities of a specific color for contour plots

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means, contour, scatter-plot

This question is in reference to visualization of EM clustering(or K-means) of 2D gaussian data. Say, I have displayed 3 clusters obtained from EM in a scatter plot with 3 different colors(say r,g,b) for the data samples of 3 clusters. Now I want to plot elliptical contours on top of this. I don't want the color of each of the three countours vary over entire colorspectrum from r to b. For contours of cluster 1, I want varying intensities of red, for cluster 2, I want varying intensities of blue and same of cluster 3. I have set the number of concentric contours to be 5 and tried passing a Color array as follows, but it did not work.

```
ColorVec   = ['r' ; 'g' ; 'b' ; 'm' ; 'c' ; 'y'; 'b'];
String2RBG = @(C)rem(floor((strfind('kbgcrmyw', C) - 1) * [0.25 0.5 1]), 2);
x = -3:0.1:4;
y = -3:0.1:4;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
for k=1:numberOfClusters
        Z = mvnpdf([X(:) Y(:)],estimatedMu(k,:),estimatedSigma{k});
        Z = reshape(Z,length(y),length(x));
        ColorVecConcentricCountours = [String2RBG(ColorVec(k));String2RBG(ColorVec(k))/1.2;String2RBG(ColorVec(k))/1.4;String2RBG(ColorVec(k))/1.6;String2RBG(ColorVec(k))/1.8];
        contour(X,Y,Z,5,'color',ColorVecConcentricCountours);hold on;
end
```

Use of ColorVecConcentricCountours throws an error, but if I give ColorVec(k), it gives a single shade of r, g or b for all 5 contours which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contour plots are groups of patch objects.  Patch objects have an 'EdgeColor' property, which is what sets what we'd call the line color of the contours.  You can set the edge colors of all contour objects in the figure with the `contourcmap` function, but since you want separate control over each of the groups of lines that won't work.  What you can do, however, is to address the patch objects themselves and change the edge color of each one separately.

To start, I have written functions called `green`, `cyan`, and the rest of the RGB + CYM colors that allow me to use those as colormaps in addition to the built-in ones.  The `green` function looks like this:

```
function G = green(m)
%GREEN   Green Colormap
%   GREEN(M) is an M-by-3 matrix colormap for increasing red intensity.
%   GREEN, by itself, is the same length as the current figure's
%   colormap. If no figure exists, MATLAB creates one.
%
%   See also RED, JET, HSV, HOT, PINK, FLAG, COLORMAP, RGBPLOT.


if nargin < 1
   m = size(get(gcf,'colormap'),1);
end

G = zeros(m,3);
G(:,2) = (0:(1/(m-1)):1);
```

You can take a look at the built-in functions to see how this one is similar.  To run the code below you'll need a `cyan` function as well (or change that function call to whatever colormap function you'd like).

Armed with a couple of contour plots put into the same axes and their handles (`H1` and `H2` below) we can pull out the levels the contours are drawn at with the contour group's `LevelList` property, yielding a vector of each contour level.  Each of the contour patch objects (children of the group) has the level that line was drawn at saved in the patch object's `UserData` property.  We can use the group's `LevelList` property to make a matrix of colors we want to use, using the colormap function call, then the position of the contour line's level in the `LevelList` vector is the row of the colormap that we want to use to color that line.  Change the `EdgeColor` of the patch object to that color for each line and we're good to go.  Two groups are drawn here to show how to get two contour groups with different colors.

```
figure()
[C1, H1] = contour(linspace(-50, 0, 50), linspace(-50, 0, 50), peaks(50), 50);
hold on
[C2, H2] = contour(linspace(0, 50, 50), linspace(0, 50, 50), peaks(50), 20);
hold off
axis([-50 50 -50 50]);

levels1 = get(H1, 'LevelList');
cmap1 = green(numel(levels1));
child1 = get(H1, 'Children');

for m = 1:numel(child1)

    cmapHere = cmap1(levels1 == get(child1(m), 'UserData'), :);
    set(child1(m), 'EdgeColor', cmapHere);

end

levels2 = get(H2, 'LevelList');
cmap2 = cyan(numel(levels2));
child2 = get(H2, 'Children');

for m = 1:numel(child2)

    cmapHere = cmap2(levels2 == get(child2(m), 'UserData'), :);
    set(child2(m), 'EdgeColor', cmapHere);

end
```